# tableView Index # for Numbers?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an indexed `tableView` that displays a list of songs from the user's iPod library.  But the sections start with 1, 2, etc., because I have songs that start with numbers.  **How do I group all songs that start with a number into a section '#' in my index?**

Right now this is my app (left) compared to what I'd like it to be (right, Music.app).  I've highlighted where the # should go (at the end of my index):

[image: Examples]

This is my code so far in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
songs = [songsQuery items];

NSMutableDictionary *songsInitials;

songsInitials = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
self.alphabetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i< songs.count; i++)
{
    NSString *firstletter=[[[songs objectAtIndex:i] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] substringToIndex:1];

    if (songsInitials[firstletter] == nil) {
            songsInitials[firstletter] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [self.alphabetArray addObject:firstletter];
    }  

    [songsInitials[firstletter] addObject:songs[i]];

}

[self.alphabetArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];   //sorting array in ascending array

self.songsInitials = songsInitials;
```

....and my `tableView` data source:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _alphabetArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [_songsInitials[_alphabetArray[section]] count];
}

-(NSString *)titleForRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{

    NSString *firstLetter = _alphabetArray[indexpath.section];
    MPMediaItem *myItem = [_songsInitials[firstLetter] objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

    return [myItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return self.alphabetArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    NSIndexPath *indexpath;

    for (int i=0; i < self.alphabetArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *titleToSearch=[self.alphabetArray objectAtIndex:i];  //getting sectiontitle from array
        if ([title isEqualToString:titleToSearch])  // checking if title from tableview and sectiontitle are same
        {
            indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i];
            // scrolling the tableview to required section
            [self.songsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexpath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
    return indexpath.section;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.textLabel.text= [self titleForRow:indexPath];  //getting cell content

    return cell;
}
```

**This is what I've tried so far, adjusting the `for loop` in `viewDidLoad`:**

```
for (int i=0; i< songs.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *firstletter=[[[songs objectAtIndex:i] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] substringToIndex:1];
        if (songsInitials[firstletter] == nil) {
            NSString *songsInitialsFirstLetter = songsInitials[firstletter];

            if ([self stringIsNumeric:songsInitialsFirstLetter]){
                songsInitials[firstletter] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [self.alphabetArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#"]];
                NSLog(@"There are numbers!");
            }
            else if (![self stringIsNumeric:songsInitialsFirstLetter]){
                songsInitials[firstletter] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [self.alphabetArray addObject:firstletter];
            }

        }

        [songsInitials[firstletter] addObject:songs[i]];

    }

-(BOOL) stringIsNumeric:(NSString *) str {
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:str];
    return !!number; // If the string is not numeric, number will be nil
}
```

...but it didn't work.  I've searched around but I can't find any other questions that ask this, am I missing something obvious here?  Any help would be much appreciated!  :)

Comment: In what way did it not work. Did you debug (particularly `        if (songsInitials[firstletter] == nil) {
            NSString *songsInitialsFirstLetter = songsInitials[firstletter];`)

Comment: @Wain Yep, I that bit worked correctly, but @ user3802077 has almost found the solution, I just don't know how to add the # to the end of my array.  :)

Comment: Look into the `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` class. It is really helpful for this sort of thing.

Comment: I used these three methods here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html - and # is now at the bottom of my index, but in the actual table, the # is at the top

Comment: @rmaddy I think the trouble is `[self.alphabetArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];` - if I delete this line, section A is at the top, but for some strange reason, alphabetArray ends like 'X, #, Y,Z'.  Not 'X,Y,Z,#'.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the problem.  Something silly on my part, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not test but changing first letter before looking in the arrays would give better result.
After the sort, not sure where the symbol (#) will end tough, you may have to manual push it to the end.

```
for (int i=0; i< songs.count; i++)
{
    NSString *firstletter=[[[songs objectAtIndex:i] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] substringToIndex:1];
    NSScanner *ns = [NSScanner scannerWithString:firstletter];
    if ( [ns scanInt:NULL] )
    {
         firstLetter = @"#";
    }

    if (songsInitials[firstletter] == nil) {
        songsInitials[firstletter] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.alphabetArray addObject:firstletter];
    }  

    [songsInitials[firstletter] addObject:songs[i]];

}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, it worked!  It now appears at the top of the index though, how would I manually push it to the end?  I'm pretty sure this is the corect code but I don't know where to put it - `             [self.alphabetArray insertObject:firstletter atIndex:[self.alphabetArray count] - 1];`